# What is the difference between "might be" and "would be"?

Tags: difference, modal-verbs

To me both might and would appear to have similar meaning. E.g. consider the following sentences:.

> 1. I think taking some rest after work would be good.
> 2. I think taking some rest after work might be good.

The only difference I see is that *would* sounds more assuring than *might*. That is, in #1 speaker is more inclined to accept the fact that having some rest will be good, but in #2 speaker isn't sure about it. In #2 it is like 50/50, it can be good and it cannot be.

So, what is the difference between would and might?

Answer (score 1):

As you pointed out, the main (and probably the most striking) difference between '*might be*' and '*would be*' is in the **degree of certainty**.

> I think taking some rest after work **would be** good.

'*would*' is a modal verbs, and is the past tense of '*will*'. By using '*will*', the certainty of the event happening is *most likely*. The speaker thinks that taking a rest after work is a good thing to do, and he is almost completely certain that this is advisable.

> I think taking some rest after work **might be** good.

Much like '*would*', '*might*' is also a modal verb, and is the past tense of '*may*'. In terms of certainty, '*might*' or '*may*' has a lesser degree of certainty, when compared to '*would*' or '*will*'. The speaker suggests that resting is a good option, after work, and he is certain that this is true, with a hint of probability of the statement's validity.

Other than that, I don't see any striking differences between the two.

A few good reads:

- http://www.differencebetween.net/language/words-language/difference-between-would-and-might/
- http://www.grammar-quizzes.com/modal1.html
- http://www.grammar-quizzes.com/modal1.html